# How to detect when users are logout with Session timeout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web-push

I am implementing web-push notifications, it works fine except one problem with the Session timeout. On our web, users will be log out after the Session is expired. However, at that time user may have closed the tab/ the browser.
How can I detect the time the Session expired so that I can stop sending notifications to this user.

**Update:**
I have the Session which will be expired after 30 mins (sessionState timeout = "30"). A user logins, and then closes the tab without logout; after 30 mins he will be logout. But he still receives notifications.

Comment: I don't think you should worry about this. When the visitor returns to the page the notifications stored in the Push Server will be delivered.

Comment: @PepitoSh: thank you but the web push in running in a Service worker so once user opens the browser, notifications will pop up. Then clicking the webpush notifications will direct to web  but it will then redirect to the login page because user has not been login.

Comment: But then your problem is something else: How to log users automatically in when they click a notification. There are solutions to this problem.

Comment: @PepitoSh: so I mean after the time the session is expired (which would mean that the user has effectively logout), I don't want the webpush to send web push notifications to this endpoint / browser anymore. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I would not mix together session timeout with logout. Session is represented by an object on your server side. When and how you destroy this object is up to you: after timeout or after explicit logout. If you do not have information about the user closing the window, you can invalidate the session only after timeout. Now, between the browser close and the actual timeout you are shooting in the dark. You either have to detect the browser close (hardly possible) or have to recover when next session started.

Comment: I agree with you on the separation between session timeout and logout, however I cannot change it at the moment (this is an existing system) Actually I only need to detect the time the Session is expired and stop sending Notifications from that time. In asp I find out that I can use the Session_End() to trigger the action (removed the user from push subscription). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m not complettly sure if this is the anwser but maybe it help you.

First you can get a event when ever a user session is end. So in this event you can end the push notification.

To achive this just add the following line of code to your Global.asax

```
    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //End push notification
    }
```

To achive that you are notice that a user close the browser or tap you need some javascript. In my example i do it with a HTTP-Request but you can also do it with some Sockets or everything else.

```
    function SendPostRequest(eMail) {
    try {
        $.post(
            "/apiacc/sessionend",
            { Value: eMail },
            function (data, status, xhr) {
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        //Error catching
    }
}

    function SetInterval(eMail) {
        SendPostRequest(eMail);
        window.setInterval(() => { SendPostRequest(eMail); }, 300000);
    }
```

And i just start the function when ever a site is loaded. So the JavaScript send every 5 Minute a Request. Which I save in the database (I use for example the E-Mailadress to authorization). On your Application start-up you create a background Task. Which will check every 5 minut if some of the session, dont get a call within the last 5 minutes. So you can end the session and the event in your global.asax will be called.

I hope this help?

Comment: Thank you @Darem I work it out by using your suggestion with Session_End :3

Comment: @ManhQuang You are welcome. When it works for you pls mark it as the correct anwser :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is,

1. save the username or any identification to session variable , Finally when Logout is clicked kill the session variable.
2. Another Option is TempData in ASP.NET , it stores the value for next page. check that variable first and then Give access to the Component.

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc

when the page is closed , tempdata will automatically killed.

Hope may this helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: OP's problem is not when the user intentionally logs off. OP does not want to send notifications when the browser windows is closed - without logout.

Comment: Yes, I want to stop sending webpush notifications when session is expired (if user clicks log out button so it should not be a problem). Thank you.